# asp .net Angularjs ajax httpPost

Tags: asp.net, ajax, angularjs

my ajax call

```
var PojedinacniPageController = function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    $scope.contactID = $routeParams.covikId;

    var odgovor = $http.post('/Home/GetContact', $scope.contactID);
    odgovor.success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.kontakt = data;

    });
    odgovor.error(function (data, status) {
        alert(status);
    });
}

PojedinacniPageController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams'];
```

mvc 4, HomeController, GetContact action:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetContact(int kontaktID)
    {

        var kontakt = _db.Kontakti.Find(kontaktID);
        return Json(kontakt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Not working, error 500. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var odgovor = $http.post('/Home/GetContact', { kontaktID: $scope.contactID });
```

Also you don't need to set `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` because your controller action is only accessible with the POST verb:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetContact(int kontaktID)
{
    var kontakt = _db.Kontakti.Find(kontaktID);
    return Json(kontakt);
}
```

This being said, it's quite a strange controller action that only returns data being accessible with the POST verb. I'd rather use the GET verb if the controller action is not modifying any state on the server but rather returning data which is your case.

So:

```
public ActionResult GetContact(int kontaktID)
{
    var kontakt = _db.Kontakti.Find(kontaktID);
    return Json(kontakt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and then:

```
var odgovor = $http.get('/Home/GetContact/' + $scope.contactID);
```